# Cancelling previous HTTP requests for Components

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I think I may have come across a bug for Chrome Browser and Angular 2 (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779).. well probably any framework that you can create an SPA with..

I have a video in a component, this loads fine the first time you visit the page, the second time too (sometimes) but the 3rd time it doesnt load..

In the chrome dev tools i can see that each time i visit the page/component it generates a new http request for that video, upon visiting the page/component for the 3rd time this request hangs and it says 'pending', now the tricky bit it I can see the same video 3 times in the Network tab and none of them have finished downloading.. I believe that this is what is making it hang as it creates 3 separate download instances..

I initialize the video in ngOnInit so im guessing thats why that happens but what i want to know is if there is anyway to kill previous http requests or else to pick up from the last one to the same asset rather than having 3 separate intances of it being downloaded across the network..

Im pretty new to angular2 so im sure there is some really smart solution to this or some lifecycle hook that i should be utilizing instead of OnInit

Comment: Could you please provide a code example to help us reproduce the case ?

Comment: By the way, the issue you're linking is a duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31014) which seems to have been fixed on November 2014. So I guess this has more chances to be linked to your code.

Comment: Are you using RxJs in your angular2 ?

Comment: I am using RxJS in angular. This specific code is simply a HTML video in a component. Looking at most of these issues in the forum it looks like there are quite a few and most of which have been ongoing years and not solved. I've launched another bug relating to it. Pretty big oversight considering chrome is considered one of the best browsers.